# PHP: HOw to store and retrieve the data entered by a user in a text field from a file?

Tags: php

HI all,

I want to Store the data entered by user in a file.

If a user enters his description in a text field, Then i Have to store the data in a file.
All the users data will go to the same file with their user name and description.

And I have to retrieve The Data from that file for a particular user.

For example if there are two users with their descriptions in the file, Then I have to retrieve a particular users description and print it on the users page.

How can I store and retrieve The data from a file?

Comment: No. I should not use a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wide choice of formats: php serialized (serialize), php source (var_export), json (json_encode), xml (SimpleXML) and so on. Note that all of those require the whole file to be loaded in memory, which might be not appropriate if you have, say, 100000 users. But in that case you're better off with a database anyways.